# Totally stuck on getting new filename from succes on dropzone

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone.js

```
var thumb_dropzone = new Dropzone(".thumb-upload-dropzone", {
url: "/includes/uploadImages.php", //# your post url
maxFilesize: "1", //#max file size for upload, 5MB
addRemoveLinks: true //# Add file remove button.
});   

thumb_dropzone.on("complete", function (file,response) {\
// here is where I need to return the name of the renamed file on the server to send to an ajax call.
}
```

This is so simply yet I can't get the name of the file that I renamed on the server. I can get the original though the file object but from all the reading response is supposed to carry whatever I write on the php side of things. I have tried simply echoing out the file name, putting it in a json object but I can't get response to be anything. What do I have to do get data back from the php being called on this success call.

Comment: Have you tried using the `success` callback:

`var thumb_dropzone = new Dropzone(".thumb-upload-dropzone", {   success: function( file, response ) {...`

Comment: file.xhr.response seems to get me anything I write back on the php page. I think this might be the answer but want to know if there is a better way...

Comment: Both ways should work. Are you sure the var `thumb_dropzone` is in scope where you're calling `thumb_dropzone.on("complete")`?

Comment: So what happens when I need more than one filename to spit out on multiple loads? I make a json object and load them in? I just feel like there should be a built in call back other than me doing custom json. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's a bit of a pain but it makes it more versatile because you can send back whatever data you want